# How to get list of neighbors with distance N from index in matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
35  1   6   26  19  24
3   32  7   21  23  25
31  9   2   22  27  20
8   28  33  17  10  15
30  5   34  12  14  16
4   36  29  13  18  11
```

I want a list of neighbors with distance 3 for each cell. For example, 
the list of neighbors with distance 3 for `(1, 1)` is:

```
[8, 28, 33, 17, 26, 21, 22, 17]
```

Visual explanation:

```
[35]    1   6   |26|   19   24
 3     32   7   |21|   23   25
 31    9    2   |22|   27   20
 -------------------
 8     28   33  |17|   10   15
 -------------------
 30    5    34   12    14   16
 4     36   29   13    18   11
```

The list of neighbors with distance 3 for `(3, 3)` is

```
[4, 36, 29, 13, 18, 11, 24, 25, 20, 15, 16]
```

Visual explanation:

```
35  1   6   26  19  |24|
3   32  7   21  23  |25|
31  9   [2] 22  27  |20|
8   28  33  17  10  |15|
30  5   34  12  14  |16|
------------------------
4   36  29  13  18  |11|
------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. You are **required** to show your own effort into solving this problem. This read like a "please write my code for me" request, which is not acceptable on SO. Please [edit] the question to contain your own (failed) attempts, preferably in code. This is called a [mcve].

Comment: You can use [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) for this. Assuming your matrix `A` is size `[M N]`, your point index is `[R C]`, and you want a vector of neighbors `B` a distance `d` away, this is how to do it: `B = A(max(abs((1:M)-R).', abs((1:N)-C)) == d);` This makes use of [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/). For MATLAB versions R2016a or earlier, you have to use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) like so: `B = A(bsxfun(@max, abs((1:M)-R).', abs((1:N)-C)) == d);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate an all-zero "index matrix" `idx` with the same size of your matrix `A`, and set the "seed" to `1`:

```matlab
A = [ ...
  35  1   6   26  19  24; ...
  3   32  7   21  23  25; ...
  31  9   2   22  27  20; ...
  8   28  33  17  10  15; ...
  30  5   34  12  14  16; ...
  4   36  29  13  18  11 ...
]

idx = zeros(size(A));
idx(3, 2) = 1
```

We get:

```
A = 
  [...]

idx =
   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Now, we use 2-D convolution, i.e. MATLAB's [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) method to create the correct index matrix w.r.t. to the distance `d`:

```matlab
idx = logical(conv2(idx, ones(2*d+1), 'same') - conv2(idx, ones(2*d-1), 'same'))
```

([Convolution is the key to success.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67650/36398))

Then, we get:

```
idx =
  0  0  0  0  1  0
  0  0  0  0  1  0
  0  0  0  0  1  0
  0  0  0  0  1  0
  0  0  0  0  1  0
  1  1  1  1  1  0
```

Since we already casted the indices to [`logical`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html), we can directly access the proper elements in the matrix `A`:

```matlab
B = A(idx).'
```

The final result:

```
B =
    4   36   29   13   19   23   27   10   14   18
```

Please notice the difference in the result as you wrote `(3, 2)` in your second example, but actually marked `(3, 3)` as "seed".

Hope that helps!

Disclaimer: Tested with Octave 5.1.0, but also works with MATLAB Online.